# How to call a function in google Colab from a .py file on google drive

Tags: google-colaboratory, drive

I have a function with two variables called check(new_doc old_doc) which is written on a .py file called checking.py that I stored on google drive.
I would like to call that function in a new google Colab notebook but when I do so I get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.
The function uses the with open method twice to read and check the documents given as a input, maybe this info can help solve the issue.

This is what I tried
`from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/gdrive') import sys sys.path.insert(0,'/content/gdrive/MyDrive/check folder') from checking import check check(new_doc old_doc)`

then I get the `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` Error